# how to delete a chart from an slide in powerpoint

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have a pptx file with one slide. There is a chart in the slide. I want to delete that chart from the slide using C# codes. I written a C# program to do it. After running the solution, when I open the converted pptx file; I get this error:

> powerpoint removed unreadable content in test2

My C# codes are as following.

```cpp
string pptxFileNameTemplate = "D:\\test.pptx";
string pptxFileNameGenerate = "D:\\test2.pptx";

File.Copy(pptxFileNameTemplate, pptxFileNameGenerate, true);
using (PresentationDocument presentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(pptxFileNameGenerate, true))
{  
    PresentationPart presentationPart = presentationDocument.PresentationPart;
    List<SlidePart> slideParts = new List<SlidePart>();
    presentationPart.GetPartsOfType<SlidePart>(slideParts);
    SlidePart slp = slideParts[0];
    List<ChartPart> chartParts = new List<ChartPart>();
    slp.GetPartsOfType<ChartPart>(chartParts);
    ChartPart cp = chartParts[0];
    string chartPartIdBookMark = slp.GetIdOfPart(cp);
    slp.DeletePart(chartPartIdBookMark);
    slp.Slide.Save();
    presentationDocument.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop all slides using application.presentation.slides and for each shape in slide.shapes collection check the shape.type, when type is chart call shape.delete